# How to prevent Eclipse from creating fragment_main.xml

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed Eclipse on a new machine and it keeps creating `fragment_main.xml` when I create a new Android Application Project. How can I prevent Eclipse from doing this, since I don't need a fragment_main.xml? I'd rather only have the activity_main.xml on start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently no way (as far as I know) to keep Android from creating a fragment when you create an Activity. You can uncheck the "Create Activity" check box and create a new Activity, but that's really all you can do.

Anyways, Fragments are good for Phone/Tablet Compatibility, and should be used in almost all scenarios except for very basic uses.

Comment: A few days ago I downloaded the Android Developer Tools which is basically Eclipse, ADT and the SDK in one package. Is this probably an older version? It didn't create fragment_main.xml there.

Comment: Probably, Android is moving toward compatibility with tablets to compete with the iPad, so they're pushing devs to use fragments.

Comment: okay I see, do you also know about the appcombat_v7 ? this "thing" is also created automatically by my Eclipse and I wonder how and what for. I don't want to use ActionBars but can't figure out how to get rid of appcombat_v7.

Comment: I think that's something related to apps being compatible with versions of Android that don't have the Action Bar. You should be able to delete everything that's associated with that.

Comment: again, that was not added in my other version of eclipse, thats why i wonder.

Comment: Yeah, I googled it, and nothing showed up other than unanswered questions, which makes me wonder what it is.

Comment: It makes you wonder and me go crazy. I literally hate it since with fragments and appcombat_v7 everything looks different than in my beginner book.

Comment: I would recommend trying to use Fragments if you can, but if its confusing, make everything in Activities, then convert it to Fragments once you're done.

Comment: can I think of them as sort of iFrames?

Comment: I believe so, yes. Fragments are really just mini Activities that run in part or all of the screen.

Comment: Ok. Well, gotta use them.

Answer (score 9):

1.Creat project normally.

2.Copy fragment_main.xml to activity_main.xml (content). Then delete fragment_main.xml

3.In MainActivity.java delete the following content :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

and

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

enjoy it.